# TypeError: can't access property Symbol.iterator, state[action.payload.savedVideos] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-actions, redux-reducers

I have a problem with redux. I am working on an app where you can save a note about your youtube video. Everything is working fine, but when I started adding the 'ADD_ITEM' action I have the same mistake every time with this action in my reducer. The error I have is: TypeError: can't access property Symbol.iterator, state[action.payload.savedVideos] is undefined. I am using connect method and function mapDispatchToProps seems fine, so maybe the problem is in reducer or action creator. Here is my add item function in my reducer:
`

```
 const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.savedVideos]: [...state[action.payload.savedVideos], action.payload.item],
      };
```

here is my action creator:

```
 export const addItem = (itemContent, savedVideos) => {
  const getId = () => `_${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`;

  return {
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    payload: {
      savedVideos,
      item: {
        id: getId(),
        ...itemContent,
      },
    },
  };
};
```

and my initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  saves: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHh-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film gargamela!',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHa-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film!',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHy-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film gorgonzoli!',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHy-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film gorgonzoli!',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHy-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film gorgonzoli!',
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan  the function addItem is in action creator, but in mapDispatchToProps is imported as addItemAction. Is it the action you wanted? ` const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addItem: (item, savedVideos) => dispatch(addItemAction(item, savedVideos)),
}); `

Answer (score 1):

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#creating-the-root-reducer

Assuming `savedVideos` is from the initialState, when u add video, you are adding the following object, and you want to add on to your initialState (aka initial store), you do not need to pass `savedVideos` to actions and reducer.

```
{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Hello meow',
      created: '18 may 2018',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QmyosHh-kU',
      content: 'Nowy film gargamela!',
},
```

Your action can be..

```
 export const addItem = (itemContent, savedVideos) => {
  const getId = () => `_${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`;

  return {
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    payload: {
        id: getId(),
        ...itemContent,
      },
  };
};
```

Your reducer can be

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return { ...state, saves: [...state.saves, action.payload]  }
      //or whatever new item u need to add to the state (store).
    case 'DELETE_ITEM': //bonus
      return { ...state, saves: state.saves.filter( x => x.id !== action.payload.id) }
}
```

Comment: just remember state = initialState is your storage, you add and remove items from it, everything else including calculations, fetching, should be done in actions.

Comment: I have seen in the redux  devtools that this is working, but dispatching  is not. This is the dispatch function:
   `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addItem: (itemContent) => dispatch(addItemAction(itemContent)),
});
 `                                                                                                                                    and here are formik initial values: ` <Formik
      initialValues={{ title: '', link: '', content: '', created: '' }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        addItem(values);
        handleClose();
      }}` maybe you can help?

Comment: addItem from action creator is imported as addItemAction

Comment: better to start a new question, and show your formik codes including the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain the error

> "TypeError: can't access property Symbol.iterator, state[action.payload.savedVideos] is undefined"

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.savedVideos]: [...state[action.payload.savedVideos], action.payload.item],
      };
```

What you are actually doing in your reducer is updating a property name from a variable.
Square brackets around a property name means that it's a variable.

The property name is the value of `action.payload.savedVideos`.  But that's not a valid property name because `action.payload.savedVideos` is an `array` (a `Symbol.iterator`).

You don't need a dynamic property name because you are always updating the property `saves`.  As explained by @Someone Special, you don't need to include the existing `savedVideos` in your action either because you can already access them from the state.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return {
        ...state,
        saves: [...state.saves, action.payload.item],
      };
```

Comment: Thanks for Your time and knowledge, now I will remember.